# WCF Visual Studio 2017 local development

Tags: c#, wcf

**March 27, 2020 UPDATE**

It has been 4 days and I have padded my office walls now.  :)

***BIG QUESTION***

This will only work locally if I change the following settings
Anonymous Authentication = Enabled

Does anybody know how to get around this issue with 
- IIS Express
- Visual Studio 2017

I stepped out of the work code and created a test locally and I am only stuck on one issue now.

Authentication is now my **BLOCKER**

I will need to use the settings for deployment as I do not have any control on the DEV | SIT | UAT | PROD --- IAAS or PAAS - I can only code CI and CD.

I removed all the  ----  Configuration
***This was not in the original source code***

I do have to comment out the code in the

***MultipleBindingServiceHost.cs file***

The localhost is complaining about the 2 URLs (I will revisit once I get all the security holes in the code fixed.

```
string rawUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tsRawUrl"];
                ServiceEndpoint endpoint = AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITicketService), httpBinding, baseAddress, new Uri(rawUrl));
                endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

#if (!DEBUG)
                string vanityUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tsVanityUrl"];
                ServiceEndpoint endpoint2 = AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITicketService), httpBinding, baseAddress, new Uri(vanityUrl));
                endpoint2.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
#endif
```

---

March 23, 2020

I have been trying to figure out WCF and Local Machine development for the past week and now I am coming to **stackoverflow** for the communities assistance.

I have been tasked with supporting an application that has two WCF Services

Web.config **appSettings** Settings as follows:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="tsVanityUrl" value="http://localhost:1574/TicketService.svc" />
    <add key="tsRawUrl" value="http://localhost:1574/TicketService.svc" />
    <add key="fsVanityUrl" value="http://localhost:1574/FileService.svc" />
    <add key="fsRawUrl" value="http://localhost:1574/FileService.svc" />
</appSettings>
```

Web.config **system.serviceModel**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!-- START RBD Additions for Local Development -->
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TicketBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="FileBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="TicketSystem.TicketService" behaviorConfiguration="TicketBehavior"> 
        <endpoint address="/TicketService.svc"                  
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="TicketSystem.ITicketService"
                  />
      </service>
      <service name="TicketSystem.FileService" behaviorConfiguration="FileBehavior"> 
        <endpoint address="/FileService.svc"                  
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="TicketSystem.IFileService" 
                  />
      </service>
    </services>
    <!-- END RBD Additions for Local Development -->
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I keep getting the following error:

The value could not be added to the collection, as the collection already contains an item of the same type: 'System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior'. This collection only supports one instance of each type.
Parameter name: item

This points me to the ***MultipleBindingServiceHost.cs*** file

```
protected override void ApplyConfiguration()
        {
            base.ApplyConfiguration();

            ServiceMetadataBehavior mexBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            Description.Behaviors.Add(mexBehavior);

            WebHttpBinding httpBinding = new WebHttpBinding();                                 

            foreach (Uri baseAddress in BaseAddresses)
            {
                if (baseAddress.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
                {
                    httpBinding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.None;
                    mexBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                }
                else if (baseAddress.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
                {
                    httpBinding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
                    httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
                    mexBehavior.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
                }
                //ServiceEndpoint endpoint = AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TicketSystem.ITicketService),
                //                        httpBinding,
                //                        baseAddress);
                //endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

                //Fix for 404 Vanity URL Issue
                string rawUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tsRawUrl"];
                ServiceEndpoint endpoint = AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITicketService), httpBinding, baseAddress, new Uri(rawUrl));
                endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

                string vanityUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tsVanityUrl"];
                ServiceEndpoint endpoint2 = AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITicketService), httpBinding, baseAddress, new Uri(vanityUrl));
                endpoint2.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I know I am very close and probably missing something very simple, but after spending multiple days on this I have to post on stackoverflow to get the services running on my local maching.

Answer (score 0):

WCF service application project doesn’t support multiple service contracts in one service host. One service project has one service host, we need to specify the service implemented class during starting the host. Consequently, it is impossible to host multiple service contracts in one host. We could create multiple hosts in a console/Windows NT service application so as to support multiple service contracts.

```
using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService)), sh2 = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService1)))
{
    sh.Opened += delegate
    {
        Console.WriteLine("service is ready");
    };

    sh.Closed += delegate
    {
        Console.WriteLine("service is closed");
    };
    sh2.Opened += delegate
    {
        Console.WriteLine("service2 is ready...");
    };
    sh2.Closed += delegate
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service is closed...");
    };
    sh.Open();
    sh2.Open();

    Console.ReadLine();
    sh.Close();
    sh2.Close();
}
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.